# How do I configure MongoRepository to use the new MongoClient API?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

My journey begins with me trying to configure Java driver of MongoDB to use UUID v4 instead of Legacy UUID v3 which is set by default.

I've found this solution here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mongodb-user/ZJKQpMpCMU4/dW5ATHTcAvgJ which works.

But as he states:

> Note that when using the legacy API the codec registry is ignored, so
>   this will not use the overridden UUIDCodec

it doesn't work with my `MongoRepositoy`.

This is my actual configuration:

```
@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws Exception {

    ServerAddress server = new ServerAddress(host,port);

    MongoClientOptions.Builder mcoBuilder = MongoClientOptions.builder();
    CodecRegistry codecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromCodecs(new UuidCodec(UuidRepresentation.STANDARD)),
            MongoClient.getDefaultCodecRegistry());
    mcoBuilder.codecRegistry(codecRegistry).build();
    MongoClientOptions options = mcoBuilder.build();

    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(server,options);

    return new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongoClient, mongoDataBase);
}

@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    return mongoTemplate;
}
```

If I do:

```
mongoClient.getDatabase(mongoDataBase).getCollection("test")
.insertOne(new Document("_id",UUID.randomUUID()));
```

I get:

```
{ "_id" : BinData(4,"f0u8ig4TS6KaJGK93xmvNw==") }
```

Otherwise:

```
mongoTemplate.getCollection("test")
.insert(new BasicDBObject("_id", UUID.randomUUID()));
```

result on:

```
{ "_id" : BinData(3,"mUX4PTPBJo6bIjPufHf0vg==") }
```

I know `MongoRepository` uses `MongoTemplate`, although I've set the instance to use `MongoClient` and not the old `Mongo`, still not working. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MongoClient` extends `Mongo`, which has reference to legacy api `DB` class via `getDB()`. Although you've registered the new UUID codec with `MongoClient` which can only be used when you use `getDatabase()` to get `MongoDatabase` which spring mongo template current version doesn't and uses `getDB()`. So your changes to registry are never used.

Spring MongoDB 2.0.0 versions has been updated to use new java driver api. So  your changes should work as expected against 2.0.0 version.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/2.0.0.M4/reference/html/